# Single quote in error message of text field Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I was using following code to make error messages:

```
textField.setRequired(true);
textField.setLabel(Model.of("XXXX"))
```

And it shows like this : 'XXXX' is required.

Do you guys have any idea to get rid of single quote?

Comment: What if you use `Model.of("'XXXX'")`?

Comment: It becomes double quotes

Answer (score 5):

You can define your own feedback messages using Wicket's internationalization support. Let's say your field is defined in a Java file named `MyPage.java`, then you'd need a `MyPage.properties`.

Let's say your HTML looks like this (simplified for brevity):

```
<html xmlns:wicket>
<body>
  <form wicket:id="form">
    <input type="text" wicket:id="field" />
  </form>
</body>
<html>
```

Then your property file should look like this:

```
form.field.Required=Oh no, you forgot to enter XXXX!
```

It's important to realize that the "path" of your entry in the properties file needs to match the path of the component inside your page, otherwise the message won't resolve.

Comment: Could I pass parameters to that properties?
something like: Oh no, you forgot to enter XXXX! of id ${id}

Comment: Yes, if you use `${label}`. The default value is: `Required='${label}' is required.`

Comment: yes, the default behavior of wicket when we used setLabel function, It always appends single quote. But I want to get rid of it

Comment: I understood that, I included the default to illustrate how Wicket uses it internally, and you can use the same mechanism. So in your case, it would be: `form.field.Required=Oh no, you forgot to enter XXXX! of id ${label}`